# Hibernate Search Dynamic Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am attempting to utilize elastic search with hibernate by using the hibernate-search elastic search integration. I have multi-tenant data that uses a discriminator strategy, so it would be great to index entities with that tenant identifier automatically added. This seems to work so far:

```
Session session = sessionFactory
                          .withOptions()
                            .tenantIdentifier("parkId-" + p.getId().toString())
                          .openSession();
```

However, during the index process, elastic search complains because of a `strict_dynamic_mapping_exception`:

```
Response: 
{
  "index": {
    "_index": "entities.productmodel",
    "_type": "entities.ProductModel",
    "_id": "parkId-1_29426",
    "status": 400,
    "error": {
      "type": "strict_dynamic_mapping_exception",
      "reason": "mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [__HSearch_TenantId] within [entities.ProductModel] is not allowed"
    }
  }
}
```

This is all *despite* the fact that I am overriding the default behavior of hibernate search and setting dynamic mapping to true, as is shown in the [docs](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/elasticsearch-integration.asciidoc#elasticsearch-integration-configuration):

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.dynamic_mapping", "true");
```

(Other settings are properly being set via this method, so I know that is not the issue.)

Any idea what I'm missing? Even setting the `dynamic_mapping` to `false` results in no changes - elastic search still complains that the mapping is set to strict. My elastic search cluster is running locally via docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to re-generate your schema before each attempt when developping. You shouldn't need the `dynamic_mapping` setting for this, but if you generated the schema before you tried adding multitenancy, and did not update the schema since, you will experience errors like this one.

Just drop the indexes in your Elasticsearch cluster, or set the property `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy` to `drop-and-create` (**NOT FOR USE IN PRODUCTION, YOU WILL LOSE ALL INDEX DATA**). See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-schema-management-strategy) for more information about schema generation.

Answer (score 0):

The tenant id field should be part of the schema if you have set `hibernate.multiTenancy` in your ORM configuration.

Did you?

If so, we might have a bug somewhere and a test case would help. We have a test case template here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-elasticsearch/hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5 .

Comment: I have set the multiTenancy strategy like so:
`configuration.setProperty("hibernate.multiTenancy",MultiTenancyStrategy.DISCRIMINATOR.toString());`


That being said, when looking at the hibernate ORM docs, I now see this in regards to discriminator multi-tenancy: "Correlates to the partitioned (discriminator) approach. This strategy is not yet implemented and you can follow its progress via the HHH-6054 Jira issue." So is the discriminator approach even possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but if it is, I'm certain you will have to do at least part of the work yourself, like [this user apparently did](https://github.com/ramsrib/multi-tenant-app-demo).